# How to compare all three attributes of date in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I want to get records within selected date range. Below is my code :

```
select * from table where create_date >= '' AND create_date <= ''
```

The code takes only date and month for comparison excluding year.
Help to compare date, month as well as year

Comment: `as well as year` or `excluding year`? Show sample data, and what you the expected results are. (If there is PHP to this question please add it, as is this is only a mysql question)

Comment: what is data type of `create_date ` ?

Comment: I need to get results including year compared

Comment: data type used for field is date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from test where create_date >= '2014-01-15' AND create_date <= '2017-01-18'
```

Its working fine

**[Check Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed767f/1)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.. Its really helpful

Comment: Welcome @Vidhya Happy to help you

Comment: Can you help me with the same scenario, but the data type is varchar(20) because table format is different here..

Comment: Check this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7029/1 with `varchar` datatype

Comment: In my table date is saved as 'DD/MM/YYYY'. Please check this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2db2f2/1

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
select * from test where str_to_date(create_date,'%e/%m/%Y') >= '2014-01-15' AND create_date <= '2017-01-18';
```

[check on fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/781e2f/1/0)

Comment: @Vidhya if your problem solve then accept the answer please